# inverse of id() function to demonstarte call be ref and value

Tags: python

I was trying to demonstrate call by reference and value and what the address of the variable is in python:

```
x = 10

print x
10

x = id(x)

print x

3457569
```

I pass x to my function by reference as x  **is an address**

```
def foo(d):

  print "the value of d is" ,**inverseid(d)**
```

foo(x)

3457569

I want the **inverse(d)** to print 10 but it prints the address!

Is there an inbuilt inverse of id() or can someone show me how to generate the value of an address similar to the * operator in C ?

Comment: The fact that `id()` returns a memory address is a *implementation detail* of the CPython implementation. You should not treat it as such.

Comment: Variables don't have addresses or `id()`s. Objects do.

Comment: Python is not C, it operates at a level abstracted from the direct machine interface.  Trying to get an object given its `id()` value is like trying to look up a chapter in a book with no table of contents.  The only way to do it is to go through the book one page at a time, inspecting each page to see if the chapter you are looking for starts on it.

Comment: @sr2222 With the added "fun" that it's easy to go through the pages of a book, but very hard to impossible (the closest I know is implementation-defined and unreliable) to enumerate all objects in a Python process.

Comment: The point was about demonstrating call by ref and value to beginners and wether it is possible in Python without reverting to VBor Pascal.